# Error converting data type varchar to numeric with substring conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

`SQL Server Table` has a column with `varchar(250)` with data like: 
(933.13755119234614, -725.869154930114746)(334.30714385628804, 103.50584506988525) and so on.

I want to compare the first two numbers in the first pair with some external values.

I use the following query which works fine sometimes but sometimes results in error converting varchar to numeric.Where am I going wrong??

```
select * 
from testentry2
where (convert(decimal(10,6),substring(data,2,10)) between 25 and 635 )
AND (convert(decimal(10,6),substring(data,CHARINDEX(',',data)+1,10)) between -99 and -9 ) ;
```

Comment: Do the numbers always have the same number of digits in them?

Comment: which cell value gives you errors?

Comment: Would make your life a lot easier if you change the datatype for numbers to a numeric datatype instead of a string. Then you don't have to wrestle with all this painful conversion.

Comment: Might be those data contains `Alphanumeric` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the entire numbers, parsing in SQL is pretty unpleasant:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(decimal(10,6),SUBSTRING(data, 2, CHARINDEX(',', data)-2)) AS FirstNumber,
        CONVERT(decimal(10,6),SUBSTRING(data, CHARINDEX(',', data)+2, CHARINDEX(')(', data)-CHARINDEX(',', data)-2)) AS SecondNumber,
        CONVERT(decimal(10,6),SUBSTRING(data, CHARINDEX(')(', data)+2, CHARINDEX(',',data, CHARINDEX(')(', data))-CHARINDEX(')(', data)-2)) AS ThirdNumber,
        CONVERT(decimal(10,6),SUBSTRING(data, CHARINDEX(',', data, CHARINDEX(')(', data))+2, LEN(data)-CHARINDEX(',', data, CHARINDEX(')(', data))-2)) AS FourthNumber
FROM testentry2
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the full numbers for the comparison you want.  You can try this:

```
where (convert(decimal(10,6),substring(data, 2, 5)) between 25 and 635 ) AND
      (convert(decimal(10,6),substring(data,CHARINDEX(',', data)+1, 4)) between -99 and -9
```

The numbers "5" and "4" may be overkill.  But the idea is simple.  If the first number were 12345678.9, then then first five digits suffice, because 12345 is outside your range.

Perhaps this will help with the formatting issue.  Otherwise, you will need to parse the strings, which is not pleasant in SQL Server (although you can find various implementations of `split()` on the web).  As a general rule, you don't want to be storing delimited lists in strings.  This data should really be separate columns and rows in another table.